# Convert Double from String

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, converters

When converting string to floating, the converter creates wrong results.

```
?Global.System.Convert.ToDouble("635705821821928755").ToString("0")
"635705821821929000"

?Global.System.Convert.ToSingle("635705821821928755").ToString("0")
"635705800000000000"
```

I am working with VB.Net Visual Studio 2012, Framework 4 on ASP.Net Webpage.

Is there any solution for converting huge numbers from string into floating?

Comment: In double and single values, the source is completely wrong to the result. 635705821821928755 is the input and the output is 635705821821929000.

Comment: `Double` and `Single` are like other numeric types - they can only hold up to a certain value with any precision.  Is `Decimal` big enough for your purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result isn't wrong, it only has lower precision than you expected. Floating point numbers have a limited precision by design, and you simply can't expect to get a result that is more precise than its limit.

You can use a `Decimal` to get higher precision. In this case it is enough for the number that you use:

```
?Convert.ToDecimal("635705821821928755").ToString("0")
"635705821821928755"
```

A `double` has a precision of 15-16 digits, and a `Decimal` has a precision of 28-29 digits.

Note: A `Decimal` is strictly speaking not a floating point number, but a fixed precision number. It's an integer with a decimal scale, so for example the number 12.345 is stored as 12345 * 10<sup>-3</sup>

Comment: In that case, the maximum value of `?Double.MaxValue.ToString("0")` will not really take each single number up to `1.7976931348623157E+308`? It will round the values?

Comment: @Nasenbaer: Yes, the `Decimal` also have a precision that is lower than the range, just like `double`. It's only for integers that the precision and range are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should use BigInteger structure from System.Numerics.

Comment: It looks like it is for Framework 4.5 but I have 4.0 only? Anyway, can you make an example? I found that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics%28v=vs.111%29.aspx

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2010 with Framework 4.0. You must add reference System.Numerics and then you can use BigInteger as a standalone type.

Comment: BigInteger BIG = BigInteger.Parse("635705821821928755");